# Error when redirecting ports with iptables: No chain/target/match by that name

Tags: iptables, firewall, routing, port-forwarding

I am trying to redirect all incoming TCP connections, originally to port 80, to port 8090, because I am running Confluence in 8090 and I want to avoid it running as **root**, which is a requirement to enable Confluence attaching to port 80.

For this I am using IPTABLES but I am getting this weird error:

```
root@psbm-ptc01b05:/# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8090
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
root@psbm-ptc01b05:/# iptables -A PREROUTING
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
root@psbm-ptc01b05:/#
```

This is my first time using iptables and I just really want this thing to work. What am I doing wrong here? What should I do?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Additional information:

My network interfaces are as follows:

```
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~# ifconfig -a
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:42:2c:2d:97
          inet addr:176.111.109.11  Bcast:176.111.109.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:42ff:fe2c:2d97/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2001:4cc0:3:f::6925/80 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25458482 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:628471 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:2767947725 (2.7 GB)  TX bytes:60340059 (60.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:466 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:466 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:109338 (109.3 KB)  TX bytes:109338 (109.3 KB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: ::2/128 Scope:Compat
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.137.96.0  P-t-P:10.137.96.0  Bcast:10.159.255.255  Mask:255.224.0.0
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Apparently I have no modules loaded. Is this bad?

```
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~# lsmod|grep -E "nf_|xt_|ip"
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~#
```

Command lsmod|grep tables also returns nothing.

The output of iptables -t nat -L -vn:

```
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~# iptables -t nat -L -vn
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 292K packets, 27M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 292K   27M            all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 981 packets, 80153 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 981 packets, 80153 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~#
```

One more probing:

```
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~#
```

More funny stuff:

```
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
root@psbm-ptc01b05:~#
```

This is a VPS by the way.

Comment: Make sure that necessary module are loaded for iptables. Is your network interface `eth0` or `eth1`? What OS are you using? Is it a VM? What modules are loaded (`lsmod|grep -E "nf_|xt_|ip"`)? What's the output of `iptables -t nat -L -vn`?

Comment: Hi, I added that information you are asking to the OP so it gets easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

check your kernel configuration against `CONFIG_IP_NF_TARGET_REDIRECT`

You need to enable that to use the -j REDIRECT target.

Comment: What commands can I perform to check that?

Comment: you need your kernel configuration for that. For example in `/usr/src/linux` `grep IP_NF .config`. Sometimes the packed config for a kernel will be saved to /boot/ for the kernel versions.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you do not have any modules loaded that you need.

By the way, which distro are you using
which kernel version : `uname -a`

Verify that modules mention by @ikrabbe are listed when you run one of these commands below :

```
grep -i =m /usr/src/linux/.config
cat /proc/modules | grep nat
find /lib/modules/*/ -type f -iname '*.ko' | grep redirect
```

Depend on your OS and kernel version, it will be easy to assit you